# How to save dictionaries and arrays in the same archive (with numpy.savez)

Tags: python, dictionary, numpy

first question here. I'll try to be concise.

I am generating multiple arrays containing feature information for a machine learning application. As the arrays do not have equal dimensions, I store them in a dictionary rather than in an array. There are two different kinds of features, so I am using two different dictionaries.

I also generate labels to go with the features. These labels are stored in arrays. Additionally, there are strings containing the exact parameters used for running the script and a timestamp.

All in all it looks like this:

```
import numpy as np    

feature1 = {}
feature2 = {}
label1 = np.array([])
label2 = np.array([])
docString = 'Commands passed to the script were...'

# features look like this:
feature1 = {'case 1': np.array([1, 2, 3, ...]),
            'case 2': np.array([2, 1, 3, ...]),
            'case 3': np.array([2, 3, 1, ...]),
            and so on... }
```

Now my goal would be to do this:

```
np.savez(outputFile, 
         saveFeature1 = feature1, 
         saveFeature2 = feature2, 
         saveLabel1 = label1, 
         saveLabel2 = label2,
         saveString = docString)
```

This seemingly works (i.e. such a file is saved with no error thrown and can be loaded again). However, when I try to load for example the feature from the file again:

```
loadedArchive = np.load(outFile)
loadedFeature1 = loadedArchive['saveFeature1']
loadedString = loadedArchive['saveString']
```

Then instead of getting a dictionary back, I get a numpy array of shape (0) where I don't know how to access the contents:

```
In []: loadedFeature1
Out[]: 
       array({'case 1': array([1, 2, 3, ...]), 
              'case 2': array([2, 3, 1, ...]), 
              ..., }, dtype=object)
```

Also strings become arrays and get a strange datatype:

```
In []: loadedString.dtype
Out[]: dtype('|S20')
```

So in short, I am assuming this is not how it is done correctly. However I would prefer not to put all variables into one big dictionary because I will retrieve them in another process and would like to just loop over the dictionary.keys() without worrying about string comparison.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As @fraxel has already suggested, using pickle is a much better option in this case. Just save a `dict` with your items in it.

However, be sure to use pickle with a binary protocol. By default, it less efficient format, which will result in excessive memory usage and huge files if your arrays are large.

```
saved_data = dict(outputFile, 
                  saveFeature1 = feature1, 
                  saveFeature2 = feature2, 
                  saveLabel1 = label1, 
                  saveLabel2 = label2,
                  saveString = docString)

with open('test.dat', 'wb') as outfile:
    pickle.dump(saved_data, outfile, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

That having been said, let's take a look at what's happening in more detail for illustrative purposes.

`numpy.savez` expects each item to be an array. In fact, it calls `np.asarray` on everything you pass in.

If you turn a `dict` into an array, you'll get an object array. E.g.

```
import numpy as np

test = {'a':np.arange(10), 'b':np.arange(20)}
testarr = np.asarray(test)
```

Similarly, if you make an array out of a string, you'll get a string array:

```
In [1]: np.asarray('abc')
Out[1]: 
array('abc', 
      dtype='|S3')
```

However, because of a quirk in the way object arrays are handled, if you pass in a single object (in your case, your `dict`) that isn't a tuple, list, or array, you'll get a 0-dimensional object array.

This means that you can't index it directly. In fact, doing `testarr[0]` will raise an `IndexError`.  The data is still there, but you need to add a dimension first, so you have to do `yourdictionary = testarr.reshape(-1)[0]`.

If all of this seems clunky, it's because it is.  Object arrays are essentially always the wrong answer.  (Although `asarray` should arguably pass in `ndmin=1` to `array`, which would solve this particular problem, but potentially break other things.)

`savez` is intended to store arrays, rather than arbitrary objects.  Because of the way it works, it *can* store completely arbitrary objects, but it shouldn't be used that way.

If you did want to use it, though, a quick workaround would be to do:

```
np.savez(outputFile, 
         saveFeature1 = [feature1], 
         saveFeature2 = [feature2], 
         saveLabel1 = [label1], 
         saveLabel2 = [label2],
         saveString = docString)
```

And you'd then access things with

```
loadedArchive = np.load(outFile)
loadedFeature1 = loadedArchive['saveFeature1'][0]
loadedString = str(loadedArchive['saveString'])
```

However, this is clearly much more clunky than just using pickle.  Use `numpy.savez` when you're just saving arrays.  In this case, you're saving nested data structures, not arrays.

Comment: I prefer accessing the element in a `()`-shaped array by `testarr.flat[0]`. For the curious reader, it is also possible to use an empty tuple as in `testarr[()]`, but this hurts readability.

Comment: Great answer!
To load the pickle and restore the dict: 
with open('test.dat','rb') as infile:
    saved_data=pickle.load(infile). 
Note you must use 'rb' if you used 'wb' (binary) to write the pickle.

Answer (score 11):

If you need to save your data in a structured way, you should consider using the HDF5 file format (http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/). It is very flexible, easy to use, efficient, and other software might already support it (HDFView, Mathematica, Matlab, Origin..). There is a simple python binding called [h5py](http://code.google.com/p/h5py/).

You can store datasets in a filesystem like structure and define attributes for each dataset, like a dictionary. For example:

```
import numpy as np
import h5py

# some data
table1 = np.array([(1,1), (2,2), (3,3)], dtype=[('x', float), ('y', float)])
table2 = np.ones(shape=(3,3))

# save to data to file
h5file = h5py.File("test.h5", "w")
h5file.create_dataset("Table1", data=table1)
h5file.create_dataset("Table2", data=table2, compression=True)
# add attributes
h5file["Table2"].attrs["attribute1"] = "some info"
h5file["Table2"].attrs["attribute2"] = 42
h5file.close()
```

Reading the data is also simple, you can even load just a few elements out of a large file if you want:

```
h5file = h5py.File("test.h5", "r")
# read from file (numpy-like behavior)
print h5file["Table1"]["x"][:2]
# read everything into memory (real numpy array)
print np.array(h5file["Table2"])
# read attributes
print h5file["Table2"].attrs["attribute1"]
```

More features and possibilities are found in the documentation and on the websites (the [Quick Start Guide](http://h5py.alfven.org/docs-2.0/intro/quick.html) might be of interest).

Answer (score 3):

**2022 Update**

There is a much simpler solution to this question using Numpy's `np.load(..., allow_pickle=True)`.

I first save an `npz` file as described in the question.

```
import numpy as np    

feature1 = {'case 1': np.arange(2), 'case 2': np.arange(3)}
feature2 = {'case 3': np.arange(4), 'case 3': np.arange(5)}
label1 = np.arange(6)
label2 = np.arange(7)
docstring = 'Commands passed to the script were...'

np.savez('test', feature1=feature1, feature2=feature2, 
        label1=label1, label2=label2, docstring=docstring)
```

Now one can read the file as follows

```
data = np.load('test.npz', allow_pickle=True)

# This is a structured array: extract the dict
feature1 = data["feature1"].item()

print("feature1 =", feature1)

# This is a normal array already
label1 = data["label1"]

print("label1 =", label1)
```

It produces the following

```
feature1 = {'case 1': array([0, 1]), 'case 2': array([0, 1, 2])}
label1 = [0 1 2 3 4 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Put all your variables into an object and then use [Pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html). It's a better way to store state information.

Comment: Thanks.
But doesn't this mean, I will have to use the same number of variables everytime? If, for some reason, I would only save one dictionary then every script loading this file with pickle would mess up the order of the stored variables.