# Python : save dictionaries through numpy.save

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I have a large data set (millions of rows) in memory, in the form of **numpy arrays** and **dictionaries**.

Once this data is constructed I want to store them into files; 
so, later I can load these files into memory quickly, without reconstructing this data from the scratch once again.

**np.save** and **np.load** functions does the job smoothly for numpy arrays.
But I am facing problems with dict objects.

See below sample. d2 is the dictionary which was loaded from the file. **See #out[28] it has been loaded into d2 as a numpy array, not as a dict.** So further dict operations such as get are not working.

Is there a way to load the data from the file as dict (instead of numpy array) ?

```
In [25]: d1={'key1':[5,10], 'key2':[50,100]}

In [26]: np.save("d1.npy", d1)

In [27]: d2=np.load("d1.npy")

In [28]: d2
Out[28]: array({'key2': [50, 100], 'key1': [5, 10]}, dtype=object)

In [30]: d1.get('key1')  #original dict before saving into file
Out[30]: [5, 10]

In [31]: d2.get('key2')  #dictionary loaded from the file
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-23e02e45bf22> in <module>()
----> 1 d2.get('key2')

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: any reason you're not using [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/pickle.html) for the dictionaries?

Comment: `with open('file.pkl', 'wb') as f: pickle.dump(your_dict, f)` should do the job.

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075661/how-to-save-dictionaries-and-arrays-in-the-same-archive-with-numpy-savez)  answers my questions perfectly. Thanks for pointing in the right direction. For an immediate fix I am doing `d2=load("d1.npy").flat[0]` as suggested in the comments. I will try porting to pickle anyway.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

It's a structured array. Use `d2.item()` to retrieve the actual dict object first:

```
import numpy as np

d1={'key1':[5,10], 'key2':[50,100]}
np.save("d1.npy", d1)
d2=np.load("d1.npy")
print d1.get('key1')
print d2.item().get('key2')
```

result:

```
[5, 10]
[50, 100]
```

Comment: Also d2.flat[0] works, as mentioned in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075661/how-to-save-dictionaries-and-arrays-in-the-same-archive-with-numpy-savez)

Comment: even , `d2.any().get('key1')` or `d2.all().get('key1')` works

Comment: it gives an error for n.load that: *** ValueError: Object arrays cannot be loaded when allow_pickle=False

Comment: Note that this the `d2` obtained from this answer is of the type `ndarray` rather than `dict`. But the question is `load the data from the file as dict (instead of numpy array) `

Comment: @Albert do `np.load("d1.npy", allow_pickle=True)`

Comment: Note to the unwary: What happens here is that when saving a `dict` as a `numpy` object, the trick used is that the entire `dict` is treated as a `scalar` so that the `ndarray` has `0` dimensions. To gain access to that one single element (the `dict`), it must be accessed via the `.item()` function on that `scalar`.

Comment: summarizing answers from all : `np.load("d1.npy", allow_pickle=True).flat[0]`. Alternative to `.flat[0]`, you may also do `.flatten()[0]`

Answer (score 8):

[pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) module can be used. Example code:

```
from six.moves import cPickle as pickle #for performance
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np

def save_dict(di_, filename_):
    with open(filename_, 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(di_, f)

def load_dict(filename_):
    with open(filename_, 'rb') as f:
        ret_di = pickle.load(f)
    return ret_di

if __name__ == '__main__':
    g_data = {
        'm':np.random.rand(4,4),
        'n':np.random.rand(2,2,2)
    }
    save_dict(g_data, './data.pkl')
    g_data2 = load_dict('./data.pkl')
    print(g_data['m'] == g_data2['m'])
    print(g_data['n'] == g_data2['n'])
```

You may also save multiple python objects in a single pickled file. Each `pickle.load` call will load a single object in that case.