# Why is my numpy array not saving all of my dictionary data?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, dictionary

I am trying to edit code that currently calculates drive times from a location for two groups of people `vets` and `SCDvets` based on the county that they live in. My goal is to edit the code so that I can calculate the drive time for a third group of people `Ineligiblevets`. However, when I add new code for the `Ineligiblevets` group (any instance in the code below where `Ineligiblevets` is visible) to the blocks of code and run the file, I receive the below Key Error.

The error references the line of code (displayed below) of the `numpy array` that contains the dictionary `countyDict` so I believe the issue is with the saving of the `dict` to the `numpy array`.

I am using Jupyter Notebooks on a Windows computer running Python 3.6. The strange thing is that the other data (`vets` and `SCDvets`) gets passed into the `numpy array` fine, but not the `Ineligiblevets` data.

I verified that the other data was in the array by using `np.load()` on the array. I have looked for similar questions but I have not been able to find any that have this strange issue.

All of the data is saved into the array except for `#Ineligiblevets`. See code below. `counties` and `facilities` are shapefiles that are used for the drive times and locations.

```
countyDict = {}

for c_SR in counties.iterShapeRecords():
    cgrps_state.append(c_SR.record[0])
    cgrps_county.append(c_SR.record[1])
    cgrps_tr.append(c_SR.record[2])
    cgrps_blck.append(c_SR.record[3])
    cgrps_id.append(c_SR.record[4])

countyDict[c_SR.record[4]] = {'State': c_SR.record[0], 'County': c_SR.record[1]}
```

```
def vetPop(popData):
    popData['id'] = popData['id'].apply('{:0>12}'.format)
    zeroList = popData.index[popData['Block Group Code'] == 0].tolist()

    c_df = pd.merge(c_df, popData, how = 'left', on = ['id'])

    c_dfCombs = c_df.groupby(['state','county'], as_index = False)['Total'].sum()

    c_df = pd.merge(c_df,c_dfCombs,how = 'left', on = ['state','county'])
    c_df['%Pop'] = c_df['Total_x']/c_df['Total_y']

    vetInfo = pd.read_csv('mypath\\County_Vetsv9.csv')
    vetInfo['FIPS']=vetInfo['FIPS'].apply(lambda x: '{0:0>5}'.format(x))
    vetInfoS = pd.DataFrame()
    vetInfoS['combined_FIPS'] = vetInfo['FIPS']
    vetInfoS['vetPop'] = vetInfo['9/30/2018']
    vetInfoS['SCD_vetPop'] = vetInfo['SCD Vets']
    vetInfoS['Ineligible_vetPop'] = vetInfo['Ineligible Vets']
    vetInfoS['countyName'] = vetInfo['county']
    vetInfoS['stateName'] = vetInfo['state']
    vetInfoS['County, St'] = vetInfo['County, St']
    pd.to_numeric(vetInfoS['SCD_vetPop'])
    pd.to_numeric(vetInfoS['Ineligible_vetPop'])

    c_df['combined_FIPS'] = c_df['state'] + c_df['county']

    c_df = pd.merge(c_df, vetInfoS, on = ['combined_FIPS'])
    c_df['#vets'] = c_df['%Pop'] * c_df['vetPop']
    c_df['#SCDvets'] = c_df['%Pop'] * c_df['SCD_vetPop']
    c_df['#Ineligiblevets'] = c_df['%Pop'] *c_df['Ineligible_vetPop']
    c_df['id'] = c_df['id'].apply('{:0>12}'.format)


    c_df2 = c_df.drop(columns = ['counted?','GIS Join Match Code','Data File Year'])

    return c_df2
```

```
def dictMaker(c_df2, facilities):
    for i in range(c_df2.shape[0]):
        ids = c_df2['id'].iloc[i]
        county = c_df2['countyName'].iloc[i]
        state = c_df2['stateName'].iloc[i]
        vets = c_df2['#vets'].iloc[i]
        SCDvets = c_df2['#SCDvets'].iloc[i]
        Ineligiblevets = c_df2['#Ineligiblevets'].iloc[i]

        countyDict[ids]['countyName'] = county
        countyDict[ids]['stateName'] = state
        countyDict[ids]['#vets'] = vets
        countyDict[ids]['#SCDvets'] = SCDvets
        countyDict[ids]['#Ineligiblevets'] = Ineligiblevets

        countyDict[ids]['all_Services'] = 'iso90'
        countyDict[ids]['VA Centers'] = 'iso90'
```

```
np.save('mypath\\countyDict3.npy', countyDict)
```

I expect the array to save all of the `countyDict` values including `#Ineligiblevets`. I expect the data to look something like this:

```
array({'State': 'Texas', 'County': 'Denton', '#vets' : 7452.34, '#SCDvets' : 8234.43, '#Ineligiblevets' : 435 }, etc, etc.)
```

NOTE: The output includes more key/value pairs (isochrones for drive times) but I have omitted those here for brevity.

The specific error message I am getting is below. `county_Table` is the function I am passing the `numpy array` to.

```
KeyError: '#Ineligiblevets'

county_dict = np.load('mypath\\countyDict3.npy').item()
---> county_df = county_Table(county_dict)
```

Comment: The answers to this question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40219946/11301900. If that doesn't help, then it would be good if you could include some test data in your post, so that people can run and debug the code. Also, in the code that you have currently posted, `countyDict` is empty and is written to file empty.

Comment: It also isn't really clear why you're using a dictionary in the first place. Some more context would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd start by looking at `county_dict.keys()`, both before `save` and after `load`.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Thanks for the link. I am reading through it now to see if its applicable. I have edited the code to include some more context and code for `countyDict`. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: I’m surprised you don’t call the `dictMaker` function, I expected that to be what actually populates `countyDict`. Some general comments: in python, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` format. Your `dict_maker` function modifies a global variable, `county_dict`. So much could be said about global variables, we could be here for weeks. They make testing, debugging and refactoring an absolute hell. Sometimes there is no way around them, but luckily, this isn’t one of those times. `dict_maker` should just take any variables it needs as parameters.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I hear you about the lowercase format, i'll keep that in mind moving forward. For the `countyDict` variable, I believe my reasoning for defining it as a global variable is because it is mentioned in subsequent blocks of code.

Comment: @kev8 sorry if i wasn’t clear. `county_dict` is fine, what should be changed is `dict_maker`. The former should take the latter as a parameter, rather than changing it directly. Am I making sense?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Yes, I think so. Editing`dictMaker` so it doesn't include `countyDict` and then passing it in as a parameter, like `dictMaker(countyDict, facilities)`. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @kev8 yes, that’s what I meant! Remember that the names of the parameters don’t matter eh, it’s a common source of confusion. `def dict_maker(county_dict, facilities):` is no different than `def dict_maker(blue_giraffe, purple_elephant` when it comes to how they are called and what they can do. In fact, since you already have a `county_dict` variable, you might want to call the parameter something like `county_dict_in` or `county_dict_arg`.

Comment: Before you make any changes, to fully appreciate the awfulness of manipulating global variables inside a function you can try to refactor your code a bit. What if you wanted to use a second county dict, called `county_dict_test`? How about a third one, at the same time? What other choice do you have than to copy/poste your `dict_maker` function, and then rename every single reference to `county_dict`. Oh and if you do forget to rename a reference, have fun debugging variables changing seemingly randomly. Fun stuff :P Now try doing all that on a function that is dozens of lines long, inside a..

Comment: ...file that is thousands of lines long ;)

Comment: Is this all the code you used to create the file?  Did you look at `countyDict` before `save`?  I see a line that creates a nested dictionary with `state` and `country` keys, but nothing that sets anything else.  You haven't run the `dictMaker` function.  As written we are left with a lot of questions as to what is being run, and what this dictionary really contains.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile That is helpful! The names of the parameters have been confusing me. Thanks for explaining that and illustrating why I shouldn't alter global variables in a function. Do you have an example of how the general `dictmaker` function would be structured?

Comment: @hpaulj This is all the code used to create the `countyDict` variable. There is more code in the file, but I thought it would be best only to post the code for the affected variables instead of the entire file. Let me know what your questions are so I answer them or edit the code above.

Comment: The key question is what exactly did you create?  There's no point in complaining about an incomplete save/load if the dictionary wasn't complete to start with.

Comment: @hpaulj I have updated the question with more information. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: You added what you expected, but what did you actually get?

Comment: @hpaulj I received the error message.

Comment: @kev8 what `dict_maker` will look like is hard to determine without some examples of the input and expected output. If all you want is to serialize and save your data, then you can [serialize your DataFrame](http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2015/03/16/Fast-Serialization), no dictionaries involved.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I actually updated my question last night to add more information about the problem and what the expected output is. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I can’t actually run the code, since I don’t have any test data! Should I just use the dummy data that @CypherX created?

Answer (score 2):

Your code can actually be much cleaner. The following solution suggests some edits that you could do to improve the function `dictmaker`. Since you have not provided any dummy data to test the solution on, I have made some dummy data and presented that below as well. I would suggest that you follow such practices of providing a minimal reproducible problem.

As I suggested earlier, there was an inconsistency in naming the variable **`Ineligiblevets`** in the fourth last line of the `dictmaker` code-block. Changing all occurences of **`Ineligible_vets`** to **`Ineligiblevets`** should fix the error. I see that you have made the change in the solution now. And if it did indeed fix the error, please leave a comment under this answer.

Now, I do not completely understand your actual logic. So, based on what limited understanding I have of what you are trying to achieve, here's my solution in making `dictmaker` simpler and producing the dictionary: `countyDict`.

## Solution

I made some dummy date (see the section below). The following code will use the dummy data to illustrate the solution.

> #### Short version of your function: `dictmaker`.
>
> Since your function, `dictmaker` was only assigning column-values from the dataframe to the `dict`, `countyDict`, you can actually do that using `pandas.DataFrame.to_dict` method. In this case, we take a transpose of the dataframe to get the type of representation you seem to look for. Also, not that I have chosen to name the `dict` variable as `county_dict` (with all lower-cases: see References)

```py
def dictmaker(df, columns = None):
    if columns is None:
        columns = ['id', 'countyName', 'stateName', '#vets', '#SCDvets', '#Ineligiblevets']
    df = df.filter(columns)
    df['all_Services'] = 'iso90'
    df['VA Centers'] = 'iso90'    
    county_dict = df.T.to_dict()
    return (county_dict, df)

county_dict, df = dictmaker(df = c_df2.copy(), columns = None)
df.head()
```

**Output**:
Modified dataframe `df`.
[image]

> **Dictionary: `county_dict`**

```
{0: {'id': 0,
  'countyName': 'County_1',
  'stateName': 'State_1',
  '#vets': 'Vet_1',
  '#SCDvets': 'SCDvet_1',
  '#Ineligiblevets': 'IEV_1',
  'all_Services': 'iso90',
  'VA Centers': 'iso90'},
 1: {'id': 1,
  'countyName': 'County_2',
  'stateName': 'State_2',
  '#vets': 'Vet_2',
  '#SCDvets': 'SCDvet_2',
  '#Ineligiblevets': 'IEV_2',
  'all_Services': 'iso90',
  'VA Centers': 'iso90'},
 2: {'id': 2,
  'countyName': 'County_3',
  'stateName': 'State_3',
  '#vets': 'Vet_3',
  '#SCDvets': 'SCDvet_3',
  '#Ineligiblevets': 'IEV_3',
  'all_Services': 'iso90',
  'VA Centers': 'iso90'},
 3: {'id': 3,
  'countyName': 'County_4',
  'stateName': 'State_4',
  '#vets': 'Vet_4',
  '#SCDvets': 'SCDvet_4',
  '#Ineligiblevets': 'IEV_4',
  'all_Services': 'iso90',
  'VA Centers': 'iso90'},
 4: {'id': 4,
  'countyName': 'County_5',
  'stateName': 'State_5',
  '#vets': 'Vet_5',
  '#SCDvets': 'SCDvet_5',
  '#Ineligiblevets': 'IEV_5',
  'all_Services': 'iso90',
  'VA Centers': 'iso90'}}
```

> ### Dummy Data

Note that we added additional irrelevant columns `UNK_Column_1` and `UNK_Column_2` to simulate a scenario when you might want to select only a few columns from the dataframe `c_df2`.

```py
def make_dummy_data():
    df = pd.DataFrame({'id': np.arange(5), 
                       'countyName': ['County_'+str(i+1) for i in range(5)], 
                       'stateName': ['State_'+str(i+1) for i in range(5)], 
                       '#vets': ['Vet_'+str(i+1) for i in range(5)], 
                       '#SCDvets': ['SCDvet_'+str(i+1) for i in range(5)], 
                       '#Ineligiblevets': ['IEV_'+str(i+1) for i in range(5)], 
                       'UNK_Column_1': ['UNK_1_'+str(i+1) for i in range(5)], 
                       'UNK_Column_2': ['UNK_2_'+str(i+1) for i in range(5)], 
                      })
    return df

c_df2 = make_dummy_data()
c_df2.head()
```

**Output**:
[image]

## References

1. [Python variable naming convention: PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)
2. [Python Naming Conventions — The 10 Points You Should Know](https://medium.com/@dasagrivamanu/python-naming-conventions-the-10-points-you-should-know-149a9aa9f8c7)

Comment: @CypherX Thank you for the thorough explanation, but unfortunately I am still receiving the error. I switched all instances of `Ineligible_vets` to `Ineligiblevets` and am still receiving the error. Then I tried your new definition of `dictmaker` instead of my code and I am still receiving the error.

Comment: @kev8 Please try to explain the problem/requirement with smaller dummy data like I did. What you have in your problem statement is not reproducible and hence not much can be done with it. Is your problem in loading a saved `dict` as a `.npy` file? If so, please state that in your problem, and remove any additional information. In my experience, if you could break down your problem into smaller reproducible problems and ask them individually on stackoverflow, the responses are often more constructive and lets you combine them and solve your bigger problem that you had started with originally.

Comment: @CypherX I have updated the question with my problem, more explanation, more code, and some dummy data. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: @kev8 Thank you for updating with more information. However, it still doesn’t simplify the problem and more importantly, it is not reproducible. Please try and make the problem smaller. Remove any function that only you would need. Think hard on what exactly you want to ask. I saw you added a new function vetpop. Perhaps that is not necessary.

Comment: @kev8 As I understand, you are trying to save a dict as a .npy file and then read it in from the file system. You have problem while loading. Some sort of filed mismatch. So, take my dummy data, convert it into a dict and then save it as npy. Load it and see if this process is working or not.  Anything beyond this is actually outside the scope of the question you asked and you could consider breaking it down into several other potential questions that you may/may not ask on stackoverflow.