# Store multiple numpy arrays into .npy file while preserving array order

Tags: python, numpy

In Tensorflow's [consuming numpy arrays](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets#consuming_numpy_arrays) documentation, it shows the following code:

```
# Load the training data into two NumPy arrays, for example using `np.load()`.
with np.load("/var/data/training_data.npy") as data:
  features = data["features"]
  labels = data["labels"]

# Assume that each row of `features` corresponds to the same row as `labels`.
assert features.shape[0] == labels.shape[0]

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features, labels))
```

Obviously, `training_data.npy` consists of two arrays: features and labels. So now let's say I have two numpy arrays `features` and `labels` that have the same 0th dimension and are ordered in the way such that every corresponding `feature` and `label` have exactly the same index. How do I save them in one single `.npy` file from which I can access the arrays using a simple key(just like the code shown above) while the array order must be preserved?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save dictionaries and arrays in the same archive (with numpy.savez)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075661/how-to-save-dictionaries-and-arrays-in-the-same-archive-with-numpy-savez)

Answer (score 0):

```
with np.load("/var/data/training_data.npy") as data:
  features = data["features"]
  labels = data["labels"]
```

In this code `data` is indexed like a dictionary. But the details of what is stored in the `npy` file is unclear.  It could be

- a zip archive created by `np.savez` (normally it would labeled as a `npz`), and `features` and `labels` are arrays loaded from their respective archived files.
- it could be a structured array, with two fields, 'features' and 'labels'.  In which case `data.shape` and `data.dtype` would useful.
- I was also going to say it could be a real dictionary with two keys and values.  But `np.save` would have put that in a 1 element object dtype array, requiring access as `data.item()['features']` etc.

So knowing more about `data` and `npy` file would be good.

Saving the arrays has the same two options - with `savez` to create a zip archive, or by creating an structured array, and saving that - in effect `np.save(data)`.

Maintaining the order and indexing of two arrays is easy - the order is normal.  As long as you slice, index and/or shuffle them in the same way, the pairing of elements between the two arrays remains.